# Not able to create NetNatStaticMapping in azure windows server 2016 core with containers tech preview 4

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to create iis container using this Blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2015/09/07/why-windows-server-containers-and-why-you-need-to-look-at-containers-hands-on/

but when i try to add NetNatStaticMapping using :

```
Add-NetNatStaticMapping -NatName “ContainerNAT” -Protocol TCP -ExternalIPAddress 0.0.0.0 -InternalIPAddress 172.17.0.5 -InternalPort 80 -ExternalPort 80
```

It shows following error.

Add-NetNatStaticMapping : Instance Nat ContainerNAT not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-NetNatStaticMapping -NatName "ContainerNAT" -Protocol TCP -Extern ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetNatStaticMapping:root/StandardCi...atStaticMapping) [Add-NetNat
   StaticMapping], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1168,Add-NetNatStaticMapping

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this by observation.

**ContainerNAT** Nat instance is there in "window server 2016 with container" so no need to create Nat instance with same name and the container should attached to **Virtual Switch** which is already there in the server.

IP provided to *-InternalIPAddress* parameter should be in range  of **Virtual Switch**.